# How to remove fields from CreateView depending on the user in Django?

Tags: python, django, form-fields, django-class-based-views

I created a CBV of which I want to remove one or more fields, depending on the user. The idea is a jobsite and if the logged in user is a recruiter, than the `employer` field should be included, otherwise it should be excluded.

**forms.py**

```
class JobCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        # exclude = ['posted', 'provider', 'ext_id']
        fields = ('title',
                'job_desc', 
                'agency_name',
                'employer', 
                'contact_name',
                )
```

**views.py**

```
class JobCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView): 
    template_name = 'job/job.html'
    form_class = JobCreationForm
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(JobCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # import the Customers of this Company
        self.fields["agency_name"].remove()
        recruiter = self.request.user
        self.fields["contact_name"].queryset = Profile.objects.filter(user_id = self.request.user)
        # if the user is a recruiter, delete the employer field.
        if Company.objects.filter(user_id = self.request.user).values('is_recruiter') == False:
            pass
            # self.fields.remove("employer")
            del self.fields["employer"]
        return context
```

The current error is `NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.

My question: how can I remove a field from the form based on logic? I tried these versions:

- `self.fields["employer"].delete()`
- `self.fields.remove("employer")`
- `del self.fields["employer"]`

Any tips?

Comment: For a start, that `if` statement will never be true; `values` will always return a valuesqueryset, which will never equal "False". You should use `if self.request.user.company.is_recruiter:`. But in any case, that code should be on the form, not the view.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to implement this (modify the fields of the form depending on user) is to do it on your form's `__init__` method. However in order for the form to access the current user you need to pass the user to it from your view. To do this you'll use the `get_form_kwargs` method. Thus, start by adding the following method to your view:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
    return kwargs
```

And now, you can add an `__init__` to your form like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if Company.objects.filter(user_id = self.user).is_recruiter == False:
        self.fields.pop("employer")
        self.fields.pop('owned_by')
```

Notice that you first initialize the form (using `super.__init__`) and then you can modify the fields to your heart's content.

Comment: Ok, help me understand this since I am fairly new to django. 1. How can  `get_context_data` print out the current user? It does not make sense after what you said. 2. why `pop`? remove or delete an item from a list seemed more logical to me

Comment: Oh, and this should be in forms.py right? (if I understand the other posts correctly)

Comment: What do you care about ``get_context_data``? You don't need to override it at all. Since you use a ``CreateView`` it will generate the form correctly, put it to context and use ``get_form_kwargs`` (which is a method of ``JobCreateView``) to pass the ``request.user`` to the form's constructor. For using ``pop`` it dosn't matter that much, it's what I usually use for removing keys from a dictionary (form.fields is a dictionary, not a list). Finally, yes, the ``__init__`` is the form's constructor so of course it has to be on forms.py

Comment: As a final comment, if you want more info about the general workings of django CBVs (and various recipies about how to do things with CBVs including what you ask) I recommend taking a look at my article at https://spapas.github.io/2018/03/19/comprehensive-django-cbv-guide/

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways to go about it.

I find having 2 separate forms `RecruiterEmployeeForm` and `EmployeeForm` may be neater.

```
class RecruiterEmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Job
    fields = ('title',
              'job_desc', 
              'agency_name',
              'employer', 
              'contact_name',
    )

class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Job
    fields = ('title',
              'job_desc', 
              'agency_name',
              'contact_name',
    )
```

Then you can override `ger_form_class` for the CBV

```
def get_form_class(self):
    if self.request.user.is_recruiter():
        return RecruiterEmployeeForm
    else:
        return EmployeeForm
```

Comment: How do you mean? Like 1 form being sub-classed (is that correct english) from the other but with an added agency field?

Comment: Yes or just have a seperate form as shown after my edit in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To send extra `kwargs` to use generic view method `get_form_kwargs` and to  get extra `kwargs` override `__init__` of form and `pop` the extra kwargs.

## forms.py

```
class JobCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
         super(JobCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if Company.objects.filter(user_id = self.user).is_recruiter == False:
            self.fields.pop("employer")

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        # exclude = ['posted', 'provider', 'ext_id']
        fields = ('title', 'job_desc', 'agency_name', 'employer',  'contact_name')
```

## views.py

```
class JobCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView): 
    template_name = 'job/job.html'
    form_class = JobCreationForm
    success_url = '/'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
      kwargs = super(JobCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
      kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
      return kwargs
```